# Store Previous SelectedValue from selectOneListbox

Tags: java, jsf

I need quite a simple solution to implement this.

I need to store a value which I selected in JSF selectOneListbox drop down and need to preserve this value in bean. So everytime when user selects a new value, the one value I should be checking with new value in drop down. How best is this to do this using session?
Any java solutions to preserve the previous selected value?

I tried ValueChangeEvent oldValue is not working because my scope is request and that's why I am looking for alternate methods.

My JSF version is 1.1

Comment: You could use session scoped bean

Comment: @JigarJoshi I have to use request scope due to other requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can try this:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputHidden id="oldValue" value="#{mrBean.oldValue}" />

    <h:selectOneListBox id="newValue" value="#{mrBean.newValue}">
        ...
    <h:selectOneListBox>

    <h:commandButton actionListener="#{mrBean.doSomething}" value="Submit" />
</h:form>
```

Then you can access the old value this way:

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean
public class MrBean {
    private String oldValue;
    private String newValue;

    public void doSeomthing() {
       if (oldValue != null) {
           // Do whatever you need when oldValue is not null here
       } else {
           // 1st request will have oldValue == null
       }

       oldValue = newValue; // Update the oldValue with newValue
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```